# Magento 2.2 - Get product attribute value in order detail Admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-attribute, sales-order

How to show **product attribute value** in **order detail** in Magento 2.2.6?
I already tried below code but not working:

File Path:

> public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml

```
$_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_code');
$_item->getProduct()->getProductAttribute('attribute_code');
```

Need Help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aasim answer works.I added below code to get attribute value.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
            $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            if ($value) {
                echo '<p><strong>'.$value.'</strong></p>';
            }
```

Comment: Please accept my ans and upvote if its useful to you!! thanks :)

Comment: $_item variable, how rendering the value. You will get undefined variable issue

Answer (score 3):

You can get product attribute value using `$objectmanager`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = $_item->getProduct()->getId();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
echo $product->getData('attribute_code');
```

You can also try this code as well ( For select option attribute )

```
echo $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->->getValue($product);
```

Comment: How to check if attribute value is not empty then echo?

Comment: Above code not working.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Is this code snippet also work for front end view or just admin?

Comment: Tried same code but it break site front end.

Comment: No. Just break the layout, like css not loading.

Comment: Yes. To show attribute value on category page (list.phtml).Use below code
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                               $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
                               $value= $product->getData('attr_code');

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88798/discussion-on-answer-by-aasim-goriya-magento-2-2-get-product-attribute-value-i).