# How to update custom order attribute from order view in magento 2?

Tags: orders, custom-attributes, magento2.3.3

I want to update some custom order attributes from the admin order section.
I have successfully created order attributes.

I want to show these attributes in the admin order edit section. I can show these values too.
But I am unable to edit and process with the form.

Please have a look at the attached image. See **Order Additional Data**.
I want to show an edit section like billing and shipping addresses.

[image]

Comment: Try this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/magento-2-2-get-product-attribute-value-in-order-detail-admin

Comment: @YoYoRoshan thank you. But i want to save the order attribute, not the product attribute.